# I am building win32 application which empties the clipboard when a screenshot is took.But the image is not emptying

Tags: winapi, clipboard, win32-process

I am building a Win32 application which empties the clipboard when a screenshot is taken. But the image is not emptying.

```cpp
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)    //callback function
{
    TCHAR str[255];

    if (!hWnd){
        return TRUE;        // Not a window
    }
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
        if ((GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & WS_ICONIC)) {
            return TRUE; // Window is minimized
        }
        if (GetWindowText(hWnd, str, 255)) {
            // LOGGER->info("In Screenshots detection, windows text: {}",wstringToString(str));

            if (_wcsicmp(str, _T("Program Manager"))){
                TCHAR proc_name[1024];
                HANDLE proc_hnd = NULL;
                DWORD proc_id;
                int flag;

                GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proc_id);
                proc_hnd = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, proc_id);

                if (proc_hnd != NULL) {
                    flag = GetProcessImageFileName(proc_hnd, proc_name, 1024);
                    if (flag != 0) {
                        if (wcsstr(proc_name, _T("chrome.exe"))) {
                            if (OpenClipboard(NULL)) {
                            //if (OpenClipboard(0&)) {
                                EmptyClipboard();  //emptyng the clipboard
                                // SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, "");
                                CloseClipboard();  //closing the clipboard

                                LOGGER->info("Screen capture on chrome is blocked!");
                            }
                            else {
                                LOGGER->error("Error in denying scrn capture on chrome!,Error: {}",GetLastError());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }
        else {
            return TRUE; // No window title
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: What's the rationale for avoiding to discover error conditions? Apparently, you fail to empty the clipboard. It would thus be reasonable to at least observe the return value of `EmptyClipboard`.

Comment: Why are you opening the clipboard with a NULL owner window? That will cause `SetClipboardData()` to fail, even if `EmptyClipboard()` succeeds.

Comment: What means `the image is not emptying.`? I try to use the code, it can clear the clipboard for me, whether it is a file in the clipboard or a picture captured by `win+shift+s`.

Comment: @dineshkarthik How did you get the image?

Comment: I took a screenshot from the chrome.

Comment: if its working is it working for EnumWindowsProc for checking all the visible windows?.if it is can you provide me the file of the working code.

Comment: I used the same code as you. How did you use chrome to take screenshots? For me, the screenshots in chrome are not saved to the clipboard, but directly available for download.

Comment: normal win+prntscrn

Comment: @dineshkarthik I can use this code to clear the screenshots in this way.Are you missing something?

Comment: @ZhuSong-MSFT now my requirement is not allowing copy paste for a screen shot. I will take care of the rest later. As you said your code is working.if you dont mind can you send the overall file?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tried to use it using hWnd still getting the same result.

Comment: @IInspectable I checked it returning success.

Comment: The code doesn't. And I have long stopped believing people when they claim to have error handling code. 19 out of 20 implementations are wrong. Show the code instead.

Comment: @dineshkarthik you can't cherry-pick what gets cleared from the clipboard. It is an all-or-nothing operation. So if text is being cleared correctly, then by definition the image must also be cleared as well. So either 1) the clear is failing, 2) the image is being re-added after being cleared, or 3) the image is not being put in the clipboard at all and you have misdiagnosed the issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah I am also thinking it might be re adding the image.Do you have any solution that i can overcome the issue?

Comment: @dineshkarthik you can’t block how other apps decide to use the clipboard. Unless you manually hook every process and detour the clipboard functions. Otherwise, about all you can do is detect the screenshot and empty the clipboard each time, but you risk a race condition trying to clear the clipboard before another app extracts it from the clipboard. What are you REALLY trying to solve? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau My point is about that race condition I want to clear before any apps extract from clipboard. Exactly that is what I am going for. I am trying to solve a app which secures some applications from being extracting data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is re-adding the image again I have checked the WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE its calling two times after clearing it.

Comment: As Remy said, you can’t block how other apps decide to use the clipboard. Unless you manually hook every process and detour the clipboard functions.